# How to create a role in CDK that will allow a Lamda to create an EventBridge target

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, aws-cdk, aws-event-bridge

In my CDK code, I've created a Lambda function that I want to create an EventBridge target. When creating an EventBridge target in the Lambda, I need to pass a `RoleArn`. I've attempted to create this role and pass the ARN to the Lambda function.

When the Lambda runs, I get the following error:

```
ValidationException: RoleArn is not supported for target arn:aws:lambda:eu-central-...
```

I'm creating the rule like so:

```
const actionFunctionRole = new iam.Role(this, `ActionServiceRole`, {
  assumedBy: new iam.ServicePrincipal('events.amazonaws.com'),
})

actionFunctionRole.addToPolicy(
  new iam.PolicyStatement({
    resources: ['*'],
    actions: ['events:*', 'lambda:*'],
  })
)
```

In the Lambda function, I'm using the role ARN like so:

```
await eventBridge
  .putTargets({
    Rule: `USER_EVENT_${images.new.userId.S}_${images.new.eventId.S}`,
    Targets: [
      {
        Arn: actionFunctionArn,
        Id: `USER_EVENT_TARGET_${images.new.userId.S}_${images.new.eventId.S}`,
        Input: '{"a": 123, "b": "YES"}',
        RoleArn: actionFunctionRoleArn,
      },
    ],
  })
  .promise()
```

What is wrong with my role definition that is making it fail within the Lambda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For lambda as target you **can't use IAM role**. Instead you [must](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-targets.html#targets-permissions) specify [resource-based policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-use-resource-based.html#eb-lambda-permissions) for your lambda function.

In other words, you have to set your **function's resource-based policy** (not execution role, these are different), to allow EB to invoke it.

Comment: Thanks, I'm confused why if I cannot use an IAM role, then why does EB target require a `RoleArn`? If this is not an IAM role, what is it meant to be?

Comment: @Fisu Normally Role is not required for the target. Did you try without it? Do you get required error?

Comment: Ah yes, I thought that it was a required property, but it is not. Removing it has fixed the issue. Many thanks!